# problem with poco on snow leopard + eclipse

Tags: c++

hey, i'm trying to work with poco on osx snow leopard, compiling via eclipse with the 64bit mac parser,

when trying to compile a simple code using Poco DateTime i get the following error :

`"Poco::DateTime::DateTime()", referenced from:
      _main in Run.o
  "Poco::DateTime::~DateTime()", referenced from:
      _main in Run.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [assignment 2] Error 1`

does anyone know why this is happening ?
i'm guessing something to do with me compiling 64bit, but installing poco i made sure it compiles to darwin 64bit as well..

SOLVED -- the error was i didn't really compile poco for 64bit..
thanks...

Comment: What is your link command?  Are you using appropriate `-L` and `-l` switches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that poco needs to be compiled for a 64bit environment in Snow leopard,
although i have ditched eclipse all together now and am using Xcode for c++, so much better.

Answer (score 0):

The linker can't find the Poco library. Like aschepler said, check the -l and -L flags. Try edit those flags on the project properties (search for the paths of the libraries)